# How to install NoMachine (NoMachine.com) on Raspberry 2

Tags: raspbian, hardware, remote

Has anyone installed NoMachine (a remote desktop program) on Raspberry Pi 2? Any success or tips you can pass on? I am having problems and am a newbie at Linux/Raspberry.  The specs:

Raspberry Pi 2 Model B 1 GB from Canakit.com
I tried packages: 
NoMachine for Linux ARMv7 DEB
and then based on some research tried
NoMachine for Linux ARMv6 DEB

With ARMv6 package I get errors on install of:
GLIBC_2.15 not found

with the ARMv7 DEB I get error msgs of form:
ERROR: Cannot validate license file
Cannot validate node license file
Failed to run '/usr/NX/bin/nxkeygen'

I think part of the problem I'm having is that I don't know Linux/Raspberry well enough.  For example, what hardware do I have?
The box says Quad Core BCM2836 CPU w/ 1 GB Ram.  Is this ARM7?  Is there a cmd line instruction to run to verify this?
I believe I'm running Raspian OS. Is there a way to verify this?  It's important because nomachine.com suggested ARM6 installation for Raspian.

Finally, if there is a better/easier remote desktop program that also works on PC/Windows, please let me know.

Comment: TightVNC is a good program, and the RPi foundation recommends it in their documentation. And I think the RPi 2 is ARMv7. I will post an answer when I get on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

Here it states it's an ARMv7 processor:

http://www.canakit.com/raspberry-pi-2-basic-kit.html

That means that in order to install NoMachine for Raspberry Pi2 you need one of the following, taken from their article which explains it very clearly:

https://www.nomachine.com/AR03M00842

Packages for ARMv7 devices have been tested on:

Raspberry Pi 2 running Ubuntu 14.10 / Linaro 15.01 
Raspberry Pi 2 running Debian Jessie 
Raspberry Pi 2 running Fedora 21 REMIX for RPi2

What OS did you install? I don't believe the device ships with an OS already installed. Maybe I am wrong?

Comment: I believe the operating system is "Raspian" which is a flavor of Debian.  I too, thought the processor was ARMv7 however as I read the documentation from nomacine.com it seemed I should be using the packages for ARMv6 if running Raspian.  This is part of my question (perhaps should be separate): how do I independently tell what operating system and hardware I'm using.  That is, it would be nice to verify that I am in fact running Raspian on Arm7 without going to the canakit website.  Thanks!

Comment: And to answer your question, the device had a simple "boot" menu that put an operating system on.  And I believe that operating system is Raspian..

Answer (score 0):

Installing is easy. Make sure you have Raspbian set up.

Some tips for installing and using NoMachine on Raspberry are available here: https://www.nomachine.com/tips-on-how-to-set-up-your-raspberry-pi-for-remote-access-via-nomachine